# How to do SUM + vertical SPLIT to receive the value of a string in the format datetime "YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My strings are in this format:

```
COLUMN Z

2022/03/11 - 16:36:01
2022/03/11 - 16:29:41
2022/03/11 - 16:34:21
```

I want to convert them to `VALUE()` to find out if they are datetime greater or less than `NOW()`, if the values in the column were formatted as datetime, I could do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(Z1:Z)<VALUE(NOW()))
```

But they're not, so to convert this type of string, the method I use is:

```
COLUMN AA

=SUM(SPLIT(Z1," - "))<VALUE(NOW())
=SUM(SPLIT(Z2," - "))<VALUE(NOW())
=SUM(SPLIT(Z3," - "))<VALUE(NOW())
```

But I couldn't make `SUM` accept `ARRAYFORMULA` vertically, `SPLIT` accepts but `SUM` doesn't.

My failed attempt was:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(Z1:Z," - "))<VALUE(NOW()))
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing enough realistic data to illustrate the issue you're trying to solve, and your hand-entered results as you'd like to see a formula produce them. A few rows should be enough. Otherwise, you're expecting the volunteer contributors here to imagine what your sheet looks like, set up their own sheet and try filling it with that imagined data to get an imagined outcome... which will be a significant deterrent. Help us help you. Share a link.

Comment: Hello @ErikTyler , thanks for the tip and next questions in more complex cases of information like these, I will publish a spreadsheet without personal data as an example, for this specific case I managed to find a way to solve my problem, I added an answer to it.

Comment: You know your data better than we do. I see potential for problems in error handling if any row of your Col Z contains stray text that doesn't match the exact format given (even a single stray space). But if you don't think that will *ever* happen, you'll be all set with your solution or the one provided by ztiaa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MMult](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en) like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Z1:Z="",,MMult(--iferror(split(Z1:Z,"-")),{1;1})<now()))
```